# Twitter Phirehose - Getting tweets if given keyword is a part of tweet

Tags: php, twitter

I am using twitter Phirehose (https://github.com/fennb/phirehose) to consume tweets.
I need to get tweets by specific keyword, I try this code:

```
$sc = new FilterTrackConsumer(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET,Phirehose::METHOD_FILTER);
$sc->setTrack(array('house'))
```

By using [settrack](/questions/tagged/settrack) I am able to get tweets which contains the needed word, but I need to get tweets also if the given word is just a part of other word. Forexample, if I search tweets which contains word [house](/questions/tagged/house), then as a result I should also get tweets which contains [phirehouse](/questions/tagged/phirehouse)[somehouse](/questions/tagged/somehouse) not only [house](/questions/tagged/house).
How to achieve this?Thanks.